# Laravel is ignoring my workbench files

Tags: php, laravel-5, workbench

I have a working Laravel 5.1 site.  I have multiple packages that are in my vendor directory as well as the workbench directory.  For the most part, when I edit one of the packages, I instantly see my changes.  However, I have one package that Laravel is looking at the vendor directory only, so no matter what changes I make to controllers, models, or views for this package in the workbench directory, nothing changes.  If I make any change in the vendor directory, that change is immediately seen.  When I first came in this morning, I was able to edit the controller and see my change, but I was having issues with Laravel saying that it could not find the view.  I ran a php artisan optimize and that fixed the issue of the view not being found, but now this Laravel only looks for code for this package in the vendor directory, not workbench.

Does anyone have a suggestion of what I can try to get Laravel to acknowledge the package in the workbench directory as apposed to the Vendor directory?

I did check permissions to see if the server just didn't have access to this directory, but that is not the case, it has the appropriate permissions.

Comment: The workbench was deprecated in Laravel 5.

Comment: We are still using it successfully with the exception of this this package only in this install, if I can provide additional information, please let me know.  Any constructive suggestions/guidance/questions that I can expand on?

Comment: As i say, that feature was removed in Laravel 5.

Comment: As I said, I was looking for constructive help feedback.  The HTML/Forms package was removed as well and can still be included for use.

Comment: The constructive feedback is, you’re using an unsupported feature. Yes, the HTML/Form package was removed from the Laravel core, but was adopted by another team who maintains them instead. The same can’t be said for the workbench functionality; it was deprecated in favour of better practices, i.e. writing your code in re-usable packages to be pulled in via Composer.